# optimizely and access to pseudoelements style properties

Tags: css, optimizely

I am about create A/B test in optimizely  that involve a change in a pseudoelement (:after :before).

What I can do to change a pseudoelement style inside optimizely (let said color).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to add some variation code like follows:

```
/* _optimizely_evaluate=force */ /*global $*/
/* _optimizely_evaluate=safe */
$('YOUR_SELECTOR::after').css('color', '#ff0000');
```

Which you enter by clicking on "show code" at the bottom right corner of the editor.

[Info about using the editor](https://help.optimizely.com/hc/en-us/articles/200039835)

[Here's what that'll look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POtCn.png)